# Azure JWT in PowerAutomate for Execution user

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, jwt, powerapps, power-automate

I am setting up a PowerAutomate flow which will be called from a PowerApp. I would like fetch a JWT token from Azure AD in Power Automate and use that token to authenticate call a REST API, return back the result to PowerApps.

However, I would the JWT token be generated for the user which executes the flow and I dont want to hard-code user credentials in the flow. There would be multiple users executing the flow and each user would have different permissions in my App ( to which the REST call is made) so I want the authentication to the app be done as a named user rather than a service account/generic account

Comment: Have you looked into Azure Application Registrations and custom connectors in combination with OAUTH security?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [@lona Varga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17437721/iona-varga) for your valuable suggestion. Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

> To authenticate your application as a named user, please try the
> following:

- Create both backend and client application registrations in Azure portal.
- After configuring these, [create a custom connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad) by updating your security setting as below:

```cs
Authentication type: OAuth 2.0
Identity Provider: Azure Active Directory
Client ID: Client ID for Client App Registration
Client Secret: Client Secret for Client App Registration
Resource URL: Client ID fot Backend App Registration.
```

- Update the redirect url by removing the existing value and add this newly created one, this is same for all connectors and it is :

```
https://global.consent.azure-apim.net/redirect
```

For more in detail, please **refer** below link:

[Solved: Re: custom connector secure using Azure Active Dir... - Power Platform Community (microsoft.com)](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/custom-connector-secure-using-Azure-Active-Directory-and-OAuth2/m-p/318678#M91668)